# What can I do to ensure that my charts diagram reload every time I choose it from my dropdown?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hey guys I have built a dropdown menu that allows me to choose from different roles. Every time I choose a role my line chart loads. When I choose another option it loads again. However, when I choose the option that I have decided for again it does not load again. So it just loads once and then not anymore. Do you have an idea of how I can solve it?

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('jobChart').getContext('2d')
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9+"],
    datasets: []
  },
});

const jobDatasets = {


  backend: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],



  frontend: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [40, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],




  mobile: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],






  full: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],






  devops: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],




  security: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],







  dataan: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],





  dataen: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],






  datasci: [{
      label: "25th Percentile",
      backgroundColor: '#c4c1ff',
      pointBackgroundColor: "645bff",
      borderColor: '#645bff',
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [27, 36, 38, 46, 50, 54, 63, 65, 71, 77]
    }, {
      label: "10th - 90th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#645bff",
      backgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [39, 66, 62, 65, 71, 80, 82, 86, 99, 107]
    },
    {
      label: "Median",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#0d0e25",
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 2,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      data: [31, 39, 46, 51, 54, 61, 65, 70, 79, 85]
    },

    {
      label: "25th - 75th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#645bff",
      pointRadius: 0,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      data: [37, 50, 51, 55, 63, 69, 73, 80, 85, 94]
    },

    {
      label: "10th Percentile",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      backgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#c4c1ff",
      pointStyle: "circle",
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineWidth: 1,
      hoverRadius: 9,
      pointRadius: 0,
      pointBorderWidth: 3,
      pointHoverRadius: 3,
      pointHitRadius: 3,
      lineTension: 0.3,
      data: [24, 31, 35, 38, 46, 48, 52, 55, 59, 67]
    }
  ],



}


document.getElementById('job-role').addEventListener('change', function() {
  chart.data.datasets = jobDatasets[this.value]
  chart.update()
});
```

```html
<select name="job-role" id="job-role" onchange="updateChartType()">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a Job Role</option>
  <option value="backend">Backend Engineer</option>
  <option value="frontend">Frontend Engineer</option>
  <option value="mobile">Mobile Engineer</option>
  <option value="full">Full-stack Engineer</option>
  <option value="devops">DevOps & Infrastructure </option>
  <option value="security">Security Engineer</option>
  <option value="dataan">Data Analysis & BI</option>
  <option value="dataen">Data Engineer</option>
  <option value="datasci">Data Scientist</option>

</select>

<canvas id="jobChart"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

update function is triggered by "change" event, (as you explicitly defined in addEventsListener parameters. Maybe consider adding

```
document.getElementById('job-role').addEventListener('click', function() {
  chart.update()
});
```

to your code...